redefine pointer to function (to a function, not an object or to a variable) inside another function
How can I redefine a pointer to a function inside another function?
In JS variables are passed by value and objects are passed by reference (these are pointers in some way). I thought functions were objects therefore I should be able to change a reference to a function.
In this example, "ptr" must print "hola" (it doesn't work).
type OnLog=()=>void;

let ptr:OnLog = ()=>{};

// change ptr
function prueba(fnc_:OnLog){

    const a:OnLog =  ()=>{
        console.log('hola');       
    };

    fnc_ = a;

};

prueba(ptr);

ptr();

It can be done like this:
type OnLog=()=>void;
let ptr:OnLog = ()=>{};

// change ptr
function prueba(){

    ptr =  ()=>{
        console.log('hola');       
    };

};

prueba();

ptr();

Or like this:
type OnLog=()=>void;
let ptr:OnLog = ()=>{};

// change ptr
function prueba(){

    return (()=>{
        console.log('hola');       
    });

};

ptr = prueba();

ptr();

But I would like to do it in the first way.

You can't. JS (and therefore TS) doesn't have "pointers" the way you mean it.  The closest you can come is as shown here where you modify a property of the passed-in thing, not the thing itself.

I knew JS doesn't have "pointers" but I thought reference are almost the same. You can pass values or referentes, I thought objects are passed as references and functions are "objects"... Many Thanks.

The edit doesn't change the answer or the linked duplicate. Functions are objects, and you can't reassign either of them via a reference to them.
